# DAX measure that counts the number of rows and weights each row by multiplying it with a value in a column

Tags: powerpivot, dax, powerbi

The following measure works as I want it:

```
Heltidsanställda har börjat:=CALCULATE((COUNTA([Anst fr o m]);FILTER(ALL(tDatum[Datum]);tDatum[Datum]<=MAX(tDatum[datum])))
```

But when I want to weight each row by its [Tjänstgöringsgrad], I get an error:

```
Heltidsanställda har börjat:=CALCULATE(sumx(COUNTAX([Anst fr o m])*[Tjänstgöringsgrad]);FILTER(ALL(tDatum[Datum]);tDatum[Datum]<=MAX(tDatum[datum])))
```

What is wrong?

**Edit:**

Here is another attempt of mine that does not work:

```
Heltidsanställda har börjat:=CALCULATE(COUNTAX(tAnstallda;[Anst fr o m])*SUMX(tAnstallda;[Tjänstgöringsgrad]);FILTER(ALL(tDatum[Datum]);tDatum[Datum]<=MAX(tDatum[datum])))
```

Comment: Isn't multiplying the  [Tjänstgöringsgrad] by the count not just the same as summing the [Tjänstgöringsgrad] with the filter applied?

Comment: Almost. I just also need to get rid of the rows where [Anst fr o m] is empty.

Comment: Just add another FILTER statement to your CALCULATE that only includes rows where NOT(ISBLANK([Anst fr o m]))

Comment: I like your thinking, but I can't get it to work. I have tried Heltidsanställda har börjat:=CALCULATE(COUNTA([Anst fr o m]);
FILTER(ALL(tDatum[Datum]);tDatum[Datum]<=MAX(tDatum[datum]));
FILTER(tAnstallda[Anst fr o m];NOT(ISBLANK(tAnstallda[Anst fr o m])))
). But I get an error message saying "... the column does not have a single value; it has many values, one for each row of the table, and no row has been specified. I can't see the start of the error message as the error message is longer than my screen is wide.

Answer (score 1):

In your Measure

```
[Heltidsanställda har börjat]:=CALCULATE(COUNTA([Anst fr o m]); FILTER(ALL(tDatum[Datum]);tDatum[Datum]<=MAX(tDatum[datum])); FILTER(tAnstallda[Anst fr o m];NOT(ISBLANK(tAnstallda[Anst fr o m]))) )
```

Can you replace

```
FILTER(tAnstallda[Anst fr o m];NOT(ISBLANK(tAnstallda[Anst fr o m])))
```

With

```
FILTER(tAnstallda;NOT(ISBLANK(tAnstallda[Anst fr o m])))
```

And if that doesn't work try

```
FILTER(tAnstallda;NOT(ISBLANK(FIRSTNONBLANK(tAnstallda[Anst fr o m],1))))
```

instead.

Comment: I want that to work, but it gives me the number of people who have started in each context. When I add the second filter to the measure the accumulation over months disappears. I don't know why. Maybe because we are trying to filter two different tables in one calculation? Another problem is that the measure only counts the number of employees who have started. I need the measure to weight each row by a number in the column [Tjänstgöringsgrad]

Comment: This "Heltidsanställda har börjat:=CALCULATE(SUM([Tjänstgöringsgrad]);FILTER(ALL(tDatum[Datum]);tDatum[Datum]<=MAX(tDatum[datum])))" is close to what I want to do. In addition to what that measure does I just want rows in tAnställda to be excluded if they have a blank value in [anst t o m].

Comment: I don't understand why the following doesn't work: "Heltidsanställda har börjat:=CALCULATE(SUM([Tjänstgöringsgrad]);FILTER(ALL(tDatum[Datum]);tDatum[Datum]<=MAX(tDatum[datum]));FILTER(tAnstallda;(tAnstallda[Anst fr o m])<>BLANK()))". When I add the second filter, the one on tAnstallda, the ackumulative behavior dissapears.